# Ajax respond is not reflected into pop-up view

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I have created a button to pass some parameters to a controller and get the response in a responsive pop-up.
But somehow when I click the button, nothing happens. No error in Dev.Option (F12), and I already make sure the parameter goes into my controller.

My reference : http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Open-Show-jQuery-Dialog-Modal-Popup-after-AJAX-Call-Success.aspx

I'm using MVC C# on Visual Studio 2010. Below is my code:

My home page, all pre-requisite Jquery are already automatically reloaded inside global.asax.

**HomePage.cshtml**

```
var externalID = "123";
var susbcrNo = "456";
<a href="#COV" onclick="javascript:CustomerOneView.displayPopUpWindow(@externalID, @susbcrNo);" >DETAILS</a>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none"/>

@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CustomerOneView.js")" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Details",
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
```

Inside **CustomerOneView.js** :

```
var CustomerOneView = (function () {
return {
    init: function () {
    },
    displayPopUpWindow: function (externalID, susbcrNo) {

        var postData = {
            externalID: externalID,
            susbcrNo: susbcrNo
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/OneViewDetails",
            data: JSON.stringify(postData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                $("#dialog").html(r);
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            }
        });
    }
};

})();

$(document).ready(function () {
CustomerOneView.init();
});
```

**My controller** :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult OneViewDetails(string externalID, string susbcrNo)
{
    Models deviceDetails = new Models();
    deviceDetails.Code = externalID;
    deviceDetails.Message = susbcrNo;

    // call log here make sure the values.
    Logger.Debug("COV called here " + externalID + " - " + susbcrNo);

    // old return
    // return Json(deviceDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    return Json(deviceDetails);
}
```

My Controller is already tied into a view that supposed to be a pop-up view. Let's call it **PopUp.cshtml**

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: So your controller action is being called it sounds like? What does the resulting JSON look like? Is there a `d` property?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker , thanks for your response, sorry I forgot to edit it, but it's still same, the button didnt reponse anything.

Answer (score 0):

I need to clarify something about C# on the server side; if you `return` a value on a function/method, it will return the value to the code that called said function/method as opposed to intelligently guessing that you want to `print` the value back to the client so the browser may then manipulate the results?

If that is the case, you need to `echo` or `print` the return value from the function/method or from where the function/method is called.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. My previous code is run successfully, without ajax, just straight forward to the view.
So in this case, I need the response on the popup. After I google it, so my idea is using ajax call, and do like I did right now :)

Comment: Pretty much; working with browsers on AJAX is very different than working with function calls on the server. Anything you want to send from the server to the browser has to be done with `echo`, `print` or `header`.